# wxpython program mirrors individual letters horizontally. how?

Tags: windows, fonts, wxpython

i'm running Boa Constructor, an old wxpython gui builder.

today, the program decided to play tricks and switched all its GUI from right to left.

far worse, when i'm editing text inside the program, each letter is reveresed.

1. What part of windows does font mirroring?
2. How to disable letter mirroring?
3. why a program i used for several years suddenly thinks i need spanish internationalization? nothing in my computer is set for spanish.
4. how can I program this behavior myself (i don't really care, just curious. any programming language solution is ok here)

i'm asking several questions together because it seems somehow related.

my settings:

- windows xp, (English interface setup!)
- python 2.5.4
- wxpython 2.8.11
- All other Windows programs are left to right,
- regional settings are for hebrew, israel

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you did, but you might want to check out the following instructions for enabling RTL: http://www.tavultesoft.com/kb/?id=41 and then see if you can reverse it.

I know wxPython can do internationalization. See http://wiki.wxpython.org/Internationalization and http://wiki.wxpython.org/RecipesI18n for information on that. Basically it involves .po and .mo files, which I doubt you can accidentally create. That's a weird issue.

Comment: yes, but how did the letters reveresed? it's supposed to be plain english

Comment: I don't really know. I did see this thread on wxPython that sounds similar to your issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/pA3zXKjbgi4 You can try setting the wx.Locale explicitly and see if that works for you too.